# Activity and service does the same work. Whats the best way?

Tags: android

I have an activity that has a button. If you click it then it does some work.

Now I am adding a GCM service in which if you receive a push msg, I need to do the same work as if the button is clicked. What would be the correct way to design this?

Do I replicate the action in the service (looks bad to me!)? OR do I have the code in a static function that can be called from  activity and service?

Thank you

Comment: Service is used for background tasks, Activity for foreground tasks. It's upto you to decide where your task lies.

Comment: But the action I need to take can be triggered from both forground and background.

Comment: It's not about 'can', it about 'should'. If there's no need for background task, then don't create a service. If you need both, then you'll have to use both.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing more, but maybe you could put it in an `AsyncTask` or a `Runnable` that you would instantiate and execute from both places.  What is the work?

Comment: What you could do is, according to your question, create a AsyncTask (if internet is involved) or something similar and execute it whenever the conditions are met, from Activity & Service. However, I will not recommend using a `static function`

Comment: The asyncTask or runnable is a good option. I assume if I use handler with runnable then it will run on the mainThread correct?  the work I do is change sharedpreferences values and send a push msg back to the sender

Comment: Why you need mainThread to change sharedpreferences?

Comment: To avoid having unwanted changing it from multiple threads at the same time (exception). I don't want to get into thread managament and locking for this task